# I got error on my eclipse when develop some apps

Tags: android

The following lines of code:

```
this.mTexture = new Texture(512,512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
this.mSplashTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/Splashscreen.png", 0, 0);
```

Result in this error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method createFromSource(ITextureAtlas<T>,
T, int, int, boolean) of type TextureRegionFactory is not applicable
for the acrguments(Texture, MainActivity, String, int, int). The
inferred type MainActivity is not a valid substitute for the bounded
parameter <T extends ITextureAtlasSource>
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onLoadResources() {
this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,
    TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mSplashTextureRegion =     BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture,
    this, "gfx/Splashscreen.png", 0, 0);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
    }
```

http://metababy.blogspot.com

http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/recent-build-change-t5514.html

Comment: @all thanks for ur reply everyone.. i appreciated so much with ur reply. thank you.